# How to use StringBuilder's AppendFormatLine

Tags: c#, stringbuilder

I can do this:

```
myStringBuilder.AppendFormat("hello {0}", "world");
```

But I can't do:

```
myStringBuilder.AppendFormatLine("hello {0}", "world");
```

I'm hoping to do `AppendFormat` and have a newline appended at the end. The error I get w/ the 2nd approach above is `cannot convert from 'string' to 'object[]'`

Comment: Where did you get the AppendFormatLine method? It doesn't exist in the StringBuilder class. Do you have an extension method somewhere in your code?  (Perhaps you are confused with the AppendLine method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `.AppendLine()` will work.

```
myStringBuilder.AppendFormat("hello {0}", "world").AppendLine();
```

Comment: Or the overload for [`AppendLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb3sbadh(v=vs.110).aspx):  `myStringBuilder.AppendLine(String.Format("hello {0}", "world"));`.

Answer (score 1):

See code below:

```
myStringBuilder.AppendFormat("hello {0}" + Environment.NewLine, "world");
```

or:

```
myStringBuilder.AppendFormat("hello {0}{1}", "world", Environment.NewLine);
```

Comment: `myStringBuilder.AppendFormat("hello {0}{1}", "world", Environment.NewLine);` would be more in keeping with the ideas behind `String.Format`, I think.

Answer (score 1):

The way I would do this is using the `AppendLine` method with a `string.Format()` call, as shown below:

```
myStringBuilder.AppendLine(string.Format("hello {0}", "world"));
```

Or even, in the new C# 6 syntax using string interpolation, assuming the 'world' string is a variable of some sort:

```
var w = "world";
myStringBuilder.AppendLine($"Hello {w}");
```